# How to set a template for a new issue in Redmine?

Tags: templates, redmine

The goal is to make users be more specific when reporting a bug.

Ususally I get a messy report "It doesn't work, please help ASAP!" from a user, so I keep asking the same questions each time -- "The why, the who-what-when, the where, and the how..."

Instead, I want to set a template for a new issue, something like this:

> 1. What page did you go? What login did you use?
> 2. What did you see?
> 3. What did you expect to see?
> 4. Why do you think this is a bug?

or whatever.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

This plugin would be very helpful, in your case,

**Issue Templates**- http://www.redmine.org/plugins/issue_templates

Answer (score 1):

The link below says that you can for the last year or so:

http://www.redmine.org/issues/1138

But I haven't yet found a description of how this functionality is used. I guess I'll have to slog through some code to find out.

Answer (score 1):

here is a patch for templating issue descriptions.  anything beyond that is still underway, and is relevant to the issue mentioned above.

http://www.redmine.org/issues/2931

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a possible workaround is to have an issue to use as a template.

Create an issue like this:

- name: Bug template
- description:

  What page did you go? 
  What login did you use? 
  What did you see?
  What did you expect to see?
  Why do you think this is a bug?

Then you can duplicate it each time you need a real issue.

The limit is with issues with subtasks. If you duplicate the parent issue you don't get the subtasks duplicated as well.